# Calculating phase diagrams (Calphad)

Tags: thermodynamics

I am calculating the phase diagrams for Li-Mg binary alloy with reference to the following text:
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5600701

In the equation used in the above paper, i am confused about whether G0 for a component is a function of temperature?

[image]

Comment: Your reference above is pointing to a dead link, could you update the reference please?

Comment: Comment to the question(v2): Please consider to link to the abstract page rather the pdf file so that users without journal subscription at least can read the abstract page.

Comment: Hi Qmechanic, although I didn't ask this question, but I could open the paper Manish was referring to; so now I added the link to the abstract that everybody can open (as you asked).

Comment: Hi @Zoltan Zimboras: Thanks. It also works for me now. Btw it is even better to use permalinks: http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/WICOM.2010.5600701

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the various $G^0$s are a function of temperature.  One can look up the generally accepted values in the SGTE Data for Pure Elements, by A. T. Dinsdale (google it - you can probably find the pdf on line). 
Usually, when doing the calculation, you select a reference state for the elements in your phase diagram, here most likely being $\mathrm{BCC}_\mathrm{A2}$ Lithium, and $\mathrm{HCP}_\mathrm{A3}$ Magnesium.  Then, you can ignore the temperature variations of those.  However, for the other elemental phases the SGTE compilation will give formulas detailing the additional free energy of that phase over the reference phase. 
The RT term is the entropy of mixing, the summation is the (usually) standard Redlich-Kister form. (Note that some older papers have an expression that looks similar, but isn't).
A glance at the Li-Mg diagram indicates no alloy phases, and no elemental phase transitions over the range of interest, so you can safely ignore the $G^0$ values unless you are trying to calculate absolute free energies with respect to some other element you have not mentioned.

Comment: Hi Jon, I added some formatting to your answer.  Can you look it over for correctness and improve any additional formatting you see fit?

Comment: Brandon - thanks for the edits.  The G0s look nice - I'll have to remember my formatting next time.  The SGTE compliation is not so nicely formatted, and actually uses descriptors like BCC_A2, which are not uncommon to find in the older CALPHAD literature.  Of course, the CALPHAD journal was orignally typeset with, well, a typewriter in the beginning...